# SQL Server data in the same record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a master table that referred by three other tables,

Table A(Id int,...some columns...) -- The master Table

Table B(Id int,...some columns..., A_Id int)

Table C(Id int,...some columns..., A_Id int)

Table D(Id int,...some columns..., A_Id int)

Where A_Id is a foreign key refers to Table A Id column.

My question now is, what if I create three columns in the master table with data type ntext, and save the table B data as xml in one column, save the table D data as xml in one column,save the table C data as xml in one column, and drop the three tables.

So in each record in table A I have all related data in the same record insted of fetching that from three other tables?

Is this a good technique?

Comment: Without knowing more about the tables and the data, we can only guess.

Comment: The only thing i can definitively say is no, ntext is not a good technique. The rest, I have no idea because we don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is replacing relational tables with XML fields a good idea? No, almost never. At the very least, you need to know why you're doing this and what you expect to get out of it. There's no tax on tables. There is a tax on I/O, but the assumption that stuffing data in XML columns means less I/O is probably wrong (depending on your use case). Also, using the deprecated `NTEXT` type is just never a good idea period -- use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or (in this case) the dedicated `XML` type instead.

Comment: I have a table having the data of dynamic screen details, and another table to hold the screen fields, and another table to hold the screen sections, So I need to keep all data in the same record, so fetch that record returns all related data of the screen.

Comment: `ntext` is deprecated; so definitely bad.  `xml` could be used for storing such data (or if you don't want that, `nvarchar(max)`.  However the key question is why would you want to / what issue are you trying to solve by doing this.  My instinct says there's not a good reason to do this.

Comment: You can very well fetch data from different tables in one single query using joins, or using multiple result sets that are processed by the client. If you're so inclined you can even collapse the related data into one single row ony the fly with `FOR XML`, if this particular use case warrants it. This still does not (necessarily) mean the data must be *stored* that way. Consider the cost of updating, for one.

Comment: doing that would make it very difficult to manage the data in your `detail rows` because there are no `detail rows` anymore. Also searching becomes more difficult, just about anything will become more difficult (and also slower). So why would you want to do that ? Maybe if we know the reason we can tell more

Comment: There are some apps retrieves the data through web service, so I need to return all data with one shot, and also the same when saving the data , since the app sends the data through the web service, so I need to post all data with one shot.

Comment: You typically solve that by having whatever receives the posted data parse the input, figure out what to do and issue the appropriate `UPDATE`/`INSERT` or `MERGE`. Things like Entity Framework specialize in these kinds of graph updates. If the data is really never treated as anything but a big blob and is never (or only rarely) accessed individually in SQL, then yes, you might consider using XML columns instead. But it's a big if -- if you started off with tables, there's probably a good reason for that.

Comment: One shot = one transaction.  You can still use multiple tables with a query over the top, or multiple statements, or a stored procedure wrapping those statements.

Comment: So I will do the following: Post the data from the app as one XML string, and parse that in the server and create a transaction with appropriate  SQL statement. And when retrieve data, will fetch data from all related tables, and create an XML string with that data and return it through the web service.

Comment: yeah that's a pretty standard approach in almost any application (regardless of the format of the data being XML, JSON, form data, or anything else, the general pattern is the same)